# Python 2.7: No module named setup tools

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

I am trying to clone and install the `keras` package from github. When I run `sudo python setup.py install`, it says `no module named setuptools`. I looked at some posts that were for python 3; however, this solutions did not work for me. I am working on a terminal from a windows computer. I am using python 2.7. I tried the following commands: `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools` from this website: https://packaging.python.org/installing/. However, nothing seemed to work.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.6c11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working on Windows then you should be typing `batch` commands, not `bash` (Linux, OSX), therefore, `sudo ...` should not be used by you.

- Firstly, I would recommend to install [`pip`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), it will make package update and installation a lot easier. Save it as `get-pip.py` and run the following in the directory the file is located `python get-pip.py`. [Official pip website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).
- Then install upgrade `pip` which will also install the latest versions of `setuptools` and `wheel` with this `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`.

Comment: when I type in just `pip`, the command is recognized. However, when I type in the full command for the setuptools, it says `no module named pip`.

Comment: Also, I'm using a terminal (MobaXterm) which mimics a linux environment. Should I still not use sudo?

Comment: A few things. Does `cmd` and the `MobaXterm` shell have access the same files? Also do you have access to a `cmd`? **If yes** use a `cmd` and the commands provided. **If no** install `pip` like you would in Linux [`sudo apt-get install python-pip`](https://packaging.python.org/install_requirements_linux/#debian-ubuntu)